# Simplify $X'(X+Y) + (Y+X.X) ( X + Y') + Z + X.Z$

Tags: computation-models, boolean-algebra

I wanna know if $X'(X+Y)$ means $X'.X+Y.X'$?

Does it have an AND gate after $X'$?

**Notation:**

- $X'$   : NOT $X$
- $X + Y$: $X$ OR $Y$ (OR gate)
- $X.Y$  : $X$ AND $Y$ (AND gate)

New to boolean, can't seem to understand this question.

Comment: What do `'` and `.` mean?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a bit of context to help understanding your question?

Comment: ' = prime
. = and
thanks for the reply.

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not seem to match... Are you only interested in learning if $X'(X + Y) = X'.X+Y.X'$ is correct or are you trying to ask something (simplification?) about the formula in the title? Also what is "prime" supposed to mean? Is it like a NOT gate?

Comment: X′(X+Y)=X′.X+Y.X′ 
I'm interested in whether is this simplification is correct. 
meaning like is there a AND gate in between X'? like is this X'(X OR Y) simplify gonna be 
X'AND(X OR Y)?

Comment: and why is there a AND GATE after X' prime? 

Trying to figure out as i need to simplify the entire expression and need to draw a boolean circuitry.

Comment: a' is a NOT gate

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any different conventinos so it is probably implied that your expression is $X'.(X + Y)$

By definition in Boolean Algebra, $+$ and $.$ are distributive over one another. This means that $x.(y+z)=xy+xz$ and $x+(y.z)=(x+y).(x+z)$.

Obviously what you are asking is the first case, so let's take $x.(y+z)=xy+xz$. This is not a proof, I am writing it like this to help you understand what is going on. In natural language, it says that the expression holds if $x$ and ($y$ OR $z$) is true. Or equivalently that $x$ and simultaneously at least one of $y$, $z$ is true. Or in other words, if $x$ and $y$ are true or if $x$ and $z$ are true. Or to return to the math notation $x.y + x.z$

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply. Will try to understand what you mean. Need time to digest. :D

Comment: So if i want to simplify my title expression, may i know how to do it?